# What happened to the sidebar's chatroom link?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, chat

What happened to the "# People Chatting" box in the sidebar? Meta still has it:

[image: chatroom link in sidebar]

but it seems to have disappeared from the main site. Is this a temporary glitch?

(I'm aware of the "chat" link in the top toolbar, but that takes you to the list of rooms, not directly to the main chatroom.)

Edit about 5 minutes later: the link is back. Hmph. (It wasn't there this morning, but I didn't post anything, because I thought it might be something temporary. When it still wasn't there 6 hours later, I thought I had confirmed it was an actual problem. Silly me.)

Later edit: I see my question isn't quite clear. The chat box was missing from english.stackexchange.com, **not** from a question page. I don't see how the explanation given for question pages could possibly apply to the ginormous list of questions on the main page.

Comment: Can you specify your browser/OS? [I can see it on my end](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7yOk1.png) (IE8/XP).

Comment: @Once: FF3.16/XP. And it's back now. I don't get it.

Comment: See http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1828/why-do-the-links-to-chat-rooms-show-up-randomly

Comment: I believe the proper phrasing for a question like this is "Eeeeek! Where's my sidebar's chat room link?"

Comment: @Robusto: yeah, yeah, yeah. I thought about it, but decided it wasn't really eeek-worthy.

Comment: You might publish a scale showing the eeek-worthiness of things, when you get around to it.

Comment: @balpha: except Jeff's explanation can really only apply to questions, not the main page.

Comment: The point is: There's no "it's always there" -- sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not.

Answer (score 1):

It should always be present on meta. On the main site, what shows on the sidebar depends on how many answers the question has.

That's because we don't want to push the related questions too far down the page, etc.

Comment: Right. Except the chat box was missing on the main **page** of the site. **Not** on a question, but on english.stackexchange.com, aka the ginormous **list** of questions.